# Use EF entity classes in WCF

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

I'm creating an app based on SOA, I've created WCF Service Project using Framework 4.0, in that I'm using Entity framework, in WCF operation Contract method I'm using the class generated by the EF, but the WCF can't recognize these objects, when I checked those classes in designer mode, they are like

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="quizTestDBModel", Name="tbl_adminUser")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
    public partial class tbl_adminUser : EntityObject
    {
        #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new tbl_adminUser object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="adminUserId">Initial value of the adminUserId property.</param>
    public static tbl_adminUser Createtbl_adminUser(global::System.Int32 adminUserId, global::System.String name, global::System.String userid, global::System.String password)
    {
        tbl_adminUser tbl_adminUser = new tbl_adminUser();
        tbl_adminUser.adminUserId = adminUserId;
        return tbl_adminUser;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 adminUserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _adminUserId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_adminUserId != value)
            {
                OnadminUserIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("adminUserId");
                _adminUserId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("adminUserId");
                OnadminUserIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _adminUserId;
    partial void OnadminUserIdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnadminUserIdChanged();

    #endregion

}
```

When I use this class in my operation contract as

```
 int adminRegister(tbl_adminUser _adminUser);
```

It give error on that method, "The operation is not supported in WCF Test Client, because it uses type tbl_adminUser"

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to create extra classes for mapping, I want to use tbl_adminUser in my operation contract thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are passing platform-specific data across a service boundary, then you are not using SOA.

Entity Framework classes are specific to .NET and to Entity Framework. Do not pass them across a service boundary.

I also note that you want to subject your clients to your naming conventions (`tbl_adminUser`), as well as the fact that there are tables involved. Why do the callers of your service need to know anything about the fact that you've implemented the concept of an "admin user" by using a table named `tbl_adminUser`?

You should create yourself a Data Transfer Object class named, for instance, `AdminUser`. It should have properties for all of the interesting public aspects of an admin user (apparently, just `AdminUserId`). It should have no behavior at all - just data.

This is the class that should be sent by and received from your service.

And, yes, you'll have to implement mapping code.

Comment: Thanks very much, yes "tbl_adminUser" this is my table and there are many attributes in it, but to show I deleted other data properties and members of tbl_adminUser, and I need to rename them, actually I want to register a user so the client should send a AdminUser object, which EF should save in DB, thats my whole Idea

Comment: So mapping on my service is must, and I'll have to do it manually, is there any other way

Comment: There are hundreds of ways to avoid writing repetitive code. Use one. [Automapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/AutoMapper.aspx) is one of many. I've never used it, though.

Answer (score 1):

The error just says that WCF Test client doesn't support your contract but it doesn't mean that WCF itself doesn't. WCF Test client is for testing the most common scenarios and it doesn't support all WCF features. Write test application or use more powerful test tool like SoapUI to validate that your service works.

Also follow @John's advices because your current design has awful naming convention, it exposes `EntityObject` based entities and it is far from SOA. By your description it is simple CRUD exposed as a service. You will achieve similar result with WCD Data Services much faster.